# How do I set default value on md-select component from angular 2 material design?

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material2

I have the following select component that gets populated from a data coming from a rest api. How Can I set default selected value on md-select?

```
  <md-select
                placeholder= "Warehouse"
                style="width: 100%"
                [(ngModel)]='selectedProductWarehouse.warehouse'
                name="Warehouse"
                required
                #Warehouse="ngModel">
          <md-option *ngFor="let warehouse of warehouses" [value]="warehouse">{{warehouse.description}}</md-option>
        </md-select>
```

Comment: when you create the group (or later with setValue) `subject: new FormControl('default option name')`

Answer (score 19):

you may try below,

Component HTML

```
  <md-select placeholder="Favorite food" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" name="food">
    <md-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value" >
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </md-option>
  </md-select>

  <p> Selected value: {{selectedValue}} </p>
```

Component script

```
@Component({
  selector: 'select-form-example',
  templateUrl: './select-form-example.html',
})
export class SelectFormExample {
  foods = [
    {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
  ];


   // setting this is the key to initial select.
   selectedValue: string = this.foods[0].value;
}
```

The key here is setting `selectedValue` with the initial value.

Check this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/ynqknljmajv).

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Strange, it does not work without md-option.
<md-select placeholder="Favorite food" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" name="food"></md-select>

Comment: @Skyware, Did you check the Plunker? I have updated with the latest Angular material.

Comment: If you are not using 'name="food" ' , it won't work.

Comment: Plunker is so slow, I have never seen it load completely.

Comment: @SunilKumar, Plunker had some issues so it was not loading, updated to stackblitz example.

Answer (score 1):

To set default value to md-select you need to set default value to the variable that you are using in [(ngModel)]. In your case:

Component Html =>

```
<md-select  
            placeholder= "Warehouse" style="width: 100%"
            [(ngModel)]='selectedProductWarehouse.warehouse'
            name="Warehouse"
            required
            #Warehouse="ngModel">
  <md-option *ngFor="let warehouse of warehouses" [value]="warehouse">
            {{warehouse.description}}
 </md-option>
</md-select>
```

Component Script =>

```
@Component({
  selector: 'select-form-example',
  templateUrl: './select-form-example.html',
})

constructor() {
  this.selectedProductWarehouse.warehouse = "default value"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use Objects in md-option value, the object reference of the default value and the correponding option in the options list are not equal.

To fix this, you need to override the default value using the correponding option in the options list before setting the FormGroup.

[Check this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46530230/1169453)