# Set default option in md-select in angular material 2

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am trying to set the default option in `md-select` of angular-material2 but to no avail.

**form2.component.ts:**

```ts
export class Form2Component implements OnInit {
    frequency = [
                {"title" : "One Time",         "description" : "", "discount" : {"value" : 0,  "type" : "value"} },
                {"title" : "Weekly",           "description" : "", "discount" : {"value" : 20, "type" : "percent"} },
                {"title" : "Every other Week", "description" : "", "discount" : {"value" : 15, "type" : "percent"} },
                {"title" : "Monthly",          "description" : "", "discount" : {"value" : 10, "type" : "percent"} }
            ]
    constructor(){}
    ngOnInit(){}
}
```

**form2.component.html:**

```html
<md-select placeholder="Frequency" [formControl]="userForm.controls['frequency']">
    <md-option *ngFor="let frequ of frequency" [value]="frequ" [selected]="frequ.title == 'Weekly'">{{frequ?.title}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

Comment: What kind of form are you using... reactive/template-driven?

Comment: I am using reactive form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using a reactive form, you can set the default value to the formcontrol. So you can do find the `frequency` you want from the array and set it as the default value, like:

```ts
this.userForm = this.fb.group({
  frequency: this.frequency.find(x => x.title == 'Weekly')
})
```

And remove `selected` from your template:

```html
<form [formGroup]="userForm">
  <md-select placeholder = "Frequency" formControlName="frequency" >
    <md-option  *ngFor="let frequ of frequency" [value]="frequ" > {{frequ?.title}} </md-option>
  </md-select>
<form>
```

**[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/MNoDw9E3SW8HPIQFBHrg?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

Component HTML

```
 <md-select placeholder="Favorite food" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" name="food">
    <md-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value" >
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </md-option>
  </md-select>

  <p> Selected value: {{selectedValue}} </p>
```

Component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'select-form-example',
  templateUrl: './select-form-example.html',
})
export class SelectFormExample {
  foods = [
    {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
  ];


   // setting this is the key to initial select.
   selectedValue: string = this.foods[0].value;
```

set the selected value to the value from the array you want it to be default, you are not using two way binding

Comment: It is also not working. It will set the value of select list but not showing the option by default.

Answer (score 0):

When you use **Objects in md-option value**, the object reference of the **default value** and the **correponding option** in the options list are **not equal**.

To fix this, you need to override the default value using the correponding option in the options list **before setting the FormGroup**.

Here is an example :

**my.component.ts**

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    myobject: Object = {id:'1323', label:'myform', service: {id:'S01', label:'Service 01': desc:''}}
    services: Array<Service> = [
        {id:'S01', label:'Service 01' , desc:'Service desc'},
        {id:'S02', label:'Service 02' , desc:'Service desc'},
        {id:'S03', label:'Service 03' , desc:'Service desc'}];

    myForm : FormGroup;

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

        // Override the service in  myobject before setting the FormGroup myForm
        this.services.forEach(srv => {
            // Compare service By id
            if (srv.id === myobject.service.id) {
                myobject.service = srv;
            }
        });

        // Set the formGroup with the myobject containing the good reference to the services array.
        this.myForm = this.fb.group(myobject);
    }
}
```

**my.component.html**

```
<md-select class="carrier-select form-control" formControlName="service">
    <md-option class="carrier-option" *ngFor="let service of services" [value]="service">{{service.label}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```