# Assigning the required value for mat-select implemented in mat-table in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have created a simple mat-table in angular 2 with two columns **acc_id** and **acc_desc**.

I am accessing the value for these columns from my **accountdetails.json** file placed in assets folder using the **accountdetails.service.ts**.

I have taken a drop-down in the **Account Description column** listing the values for the **acc_desc** .

### Below shown is my output

[image]

But here in my table i want to initialise the acc_desc value as per its acc_id from the json file with the listing in dropdown ,so that if required i can change it to other option.

### Below shown is my code

`account.component.html`

```html
<mat-toolbar color="primary" style="width:100%"> WELCOME </mat-toolbar><br/>

<!-- Table starts here -->

<mat-card>
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">

  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource1">

    <!-- Account No. Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="acc_id">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Account ID. </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.acc_id}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

      <!-- Account Description Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="acc_desc">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Account Description </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <mat-form-field >
            <mat-select style="min-width: 200px;" placeholder="" >
              <mat-option *ngFor="let dep of acc_desc " [value]="acc_desc" >
                {{ dep.acc_desc }}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
      </mat-cell>
       </ng-container>


    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns1" ></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns1;"> </mat-row>
  </mat-table>

  <mat-paginator #paginator
                 [pageSize]="10"
                 [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]">
  </mat-paginator>
</div>
</mat-card>
```

`account.component.ts`

```ts
import {Component, ViewChild, Inject, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {MatPaginator, MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';
import { AccountdetailService } from '../accountdetail.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-account',
  templateUrl: './account.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./account.component.scss']
   })


export class AccountComponent implements OnInit {

acc_desc: any;

constructor(private accdetailservice: AccountdetailService ) { }


  /* Table Starts here
  ---------------------- */

 displayedColumns1 = ['acc_id', 'acc_desc'];
 dataSource1= new MatTableDataSource<Element>(ELEMENT_DATA);

ngOnInit(){
  this.accdetailservice.accountdetails()
  .subscribe(data => {
     this.acc_desc = data;
     this.dataSource1.data = data;
  }); }

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

   ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource1.paginator = this.paginator;
  } }

  export interface Element {
   acc_id: any;
   acc_desc: any; 
  }

const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [];
```

`accountdetails.service.ts`

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class AccountdetailService {

  constructor(private http:Http ) { }

  accountdetails()
  {
    return this.http.get('/assets/accountdetails.json')
    .map(result => result.json());
  }}
```

`accountdetails.json`

```json
[
    {
        "acc_id": 1001,
        "acc_desc": "Administration"
    },

    {
        "acc_id": 1002,
        "acc_desc": "Laboratory"
    },

    {
        "acc_id": 1003,
        "acc_desc": "Staff"
    },

    {
        "acc_id": 1004,
        "acc_desc": "Office-1"
    },

    {
        "acc_id": 1005,
        "acc_desc": "Office-2"
    }
]
```

`app.module.ts`

```ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule} from '@angular/http';

import { AppMaterialModule } from './app-material.module';


import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AccountComponent } from './account/account.component';

import { AccountdetailService } from './accountdetail.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AccountComponent      
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppMaterialModule,
    FormsModule ,
    HttpModule   
  ],
  entryComponents:[ ],

  providers: [ AccountdetailService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Can anybody please tell me how can i initialise the values for the corresponding acc_id with its acc_desc as listed in my json file ,also with the dropdown to select the required.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: refer this....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41811708/how-do-i-set-default-value-on-md-select-component-from-angular-2-material-design

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to bind a variable to the `mat-select` component and fix the `value` of `mat-option`.

```
<mat-select style="min-width: 200px;" placeholder="" [(value)]="element.acc_desc" >
   <mat-option *ngFor="let dep of acc_desc " [value]="dep.acc_desc" >
     {{ dep.acc_desc }}
   </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Sample : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-isif36?file=app%2Fselect-value-binding-example.ts

Comment: the stackblitz example has manually assigned value for the variable selected

Comment: but i need to initialise the value corresponding to the acc_id from the datasource

Comment: `element.acc_desc` contains the value to assign, right ? Or I missed something?

Comment: In your screenshot, you want to have on column 2 a selected value on each line. This value is store in your element variable (property acc_desc). Am I right?

Comment: `let element` is your variable, you have access (actually, in your first column, you did it `<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.acc_id}}</mat-cell>`)

Comment: Try `<mat-select [(value)]="element.acc_desc">` I think it s ok

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166111/discussion-between-damien-vitrac-and-heena).